# [Python][Tkinter]How to delete row of 2D list by element?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to delete a row of a 2D list that stores user data by the first element, which is the ID number, on button click. My 2D list is built as followed

```
def save():
    cdata = [int(custidentry.get()), custnameentry.get(), custaddressentry.get(), custcontactentry.get(),
             custemailentry.get(), custbdateentry.get(), cgenderentry.get()]

    c_list.append(cdata)
    # print(c_list)
    createtable(c_list)
```

Table is created using entry widgets

```
def createtable(custlist):  # Creates table
for i in range(len(custlist)):
    for j in range(len(custlist[0])):
        mgrid = Entry(table_frame, width=10, bg='yellow')
        mgrid.insert(END, custlist[i][j])
        mgrid._values = i
        mgrid.grid(row=i+13, column=j+4)
        mgrid.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
```

And I use this function to assign the values from table back to their entry widgets for my other functions

```
def callback(event):  # Displays the values of each row to the entry fields
print(event.widget._values)
custid.set(c_list[event.widget._values][0])
custname.set(c_list[event.widget._values][1])
custaddress.set(c_list[event.widget._values][2])
custcontact.set(c_list[event.widget._values][3])
custemail.set(c_list[event.widget._values][4])
custbdate.set(c_list[event.widget._values][5])
cgender.set(c_list[event.widget._values][6])
```

Lastly, this is my delete function

```
def delete():
# for deleting customer in array
c_list.remove(int(custidentry.get()))
# for deleting grid
list_of_grids = table_frame.grid_slaves()
for mgrid in list_of_grids:
    mgrid.destroy()
createtable(c_list)
```

I'm not sure why I get the error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`  even though it is present as the first element. I tried `del(c_list[int(custidentry.get())-1]` but I get out of bounds error since the index would eventually be lower than the ID number. Is there a better way to delete a row from a 2D list?

Here are the examples of encountering the errors:

- Deletion by element (ID 2 was selected)
  [image: Deletion by element (ID 2)]
- Deletion by c_list row index. I deleted ID 2, then I proceeded to delete ID 3 but I can't since table index is `[1]`
  [image]

Comment: Can you provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I provided samples in my post. Hope it helps!